# Deploy across multiple webservers, remove from load balancer on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, deployment, automation

I'm wondering if there is a 3rd party application that can help me deploy a web project (website) to IIS across multiple web servers. While, taking one server out of the load balancer deploying, taking the second server out of the load balancer, and so on.

Is there an application/software that does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Microsoft's Web Farm Framework: http://www.iis.net/download/WebFarmFramework

It's allows you to setup a single IIS configuration with content and for that to be replicated across multiple web servers.